# How to hop between inner class returns when creating a new variable with chaining methods c#

Tags: c#, return-value, method-chaining

I don't know if hopping is the best word for what i want to achive (because i never learnt programming officially) basically i have a class with two inner classes here is the code

```
using System.Drawing;

namespace Leveltar_Fresh
{
   class Scene
   {
      private Image image;

      public class Sphere : Scene
      {
          public Sphere()
          {
            
          }

          public Sphere addClickable(int x, int y, int r)
          {
             Clickable clickable = new Clickable.Sphere(x, y, r);
             return this;
          }
      }

      public class Rectangle : Scene
      {
         public Rectangle()
         {

         }

         public Rectangle addClickable(int x, int y, int width, int height)
         {
            Clickable clickable = new Clickable.Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
            return this;
         }
      }

      public static Scene createNewScene(Scene scene)
      {
         return scene;
      }
   }
}
```

i tried adding a method to the outer class which i can use as another chain for my method chain this method

```
public static Scene getScene()
{
   return this;
}
```

but when i called this method in a chain i couldn't access the inner classes i did `new Scene.Sphere().addClickable(20, 20, 50).getScene()` and then i couldn't call neither of the inner classes i have more experience with java and i know there are some differences between the usage of inner classes in c# and java but what causes this and how can i fix this?

Comment: 1. Do the classes need to be nested? Typically you would only nest if you want to limit the scope of the nested class. 2. What does the Clickable class look like?

Comment: I only nested them because later when i will add all the functionallity to the inner classes they will be more organized and the Clickable is checking for mouse clicks whithin the selected region based on the shape in this case if it's a Sphere or a Rectangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. However, the reason why you can't access the nested classes after calling the `getScene()` method is because the scope of your nested classes is limited to within the parent class only.

In response to my comment *Do the classes need to be nested*, you mentioned you only needed it for code organisation and not limiting scope and so I would advise to move those classes out. This will in fact result in cleaner code.

Below I have attempted to retain your functionality and simply make your code a bit more *fluent*.

```cs
public class Scene
{
    public Scene()
    {
         ChildSphere = new Sphere();
         ChildRectangle = new Rectangle();
    }

    // 2 previously nested classes are now public properties.
    public Sphere ChildSphere { get; }
    public Rectangle ChildRectangle { get; }

    public static Scene CreateNewScene(Scene scene)
    {
        //logic...
        return scene;
    }

    public Scene GetScene()
    {
        return this;
    }
}

public class Sphere : Scene
{
    public Sphere AddClickable(int x, int y, int r)
    {
        Clickable clickable = new Clickable.Sphere(x, y, r);
        // logic..
        return this;
    }
}

public class Rectangle : Scene
{
    public Rectangle AddClickable(int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        Clickable clickable = new Clickable.Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
        // logic..
        return this;
    }
}
```

Which results in this:

```
new Scene().ChildSphere
.AddClickable(20, 20, 50)
.GetScene()
.ChildRectangle
.AddClickable(20,40,60,80)
.GetScene();
```

*I have included the `GetScene()` method only because you had it in your example. I don't think its of much use given the code you provided.*

Something to point out is in the example above, once you call this `new Scene().ChildSphere` you no longer have access(via chaining) to the original(very first) scene. In other words every additional chain will be returning the current instance at that point.

So in terms of objects returned after each chain we have:

```
new Scene().ChildSphere     // scene1 -> scene1.ChildSphere
.AddClickable(20, 20, 50)   // scene1.ChildSphere
.GetScene()                 // scene1.ChildSphere
.ChildRectangle             // scene1.ChildSphere.ChildRectangle
.AddClickable(20,40,60,80)  // scene1.ChildSphere.ChildRectangle
.GetScene();                // scene1.ChildSphere.ChildRectangle
```

If you want at any point to get back to *scene1* or some other previous parent then you'll need to implement a way of linking parent and child. It is possible but have excluded this as out of scope for this question.

Comment: Thank you very much now i see the problem now it's actually more clear i was just confused because as i said in java i can return the outer class than access anyother inner class as much as i want thanks for your help

Comment: Sure no problem. If this answers you question feel free to upvote or accept the answer. Otherwise would be handy to see what your solution was.

Comment: Actually what you just gave me was my solution so thanks again in a bit diferent way basically i add those two lines which are returning the inner classes instead of getting them and i left the Scene() constructor alone because i don't really need to use it right now also unfortunatelly i can't upvote (new acc) even tho i would but i did accepted your answer thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit hard to tell what you are trying to do here. Maybe something like this?

```
public interface IScene
{
    bool PointIsWithinScene( int x, int y);
} 

public Sphere: IScene
{
    public Sphere( int x, int y, int r) { ... }
    
    public bool PointIsWithinScene( int x, int y) { return ...; }
}

public Rectangle: IScene
{
    public Rectangle( int x, int y, int w, int h) { ... }

    public bool PointIsWithinScene( int x, int y) { return ...; }
}

public CompositeScene: List<IScene>, IScene
{
    public CompositeScene(): base() { ... }

    public bool PointIsWithinScene( int x, int y) 
    {
        return this.Any( subScene => subScene.PointIsWithinScene( x, y));
    }
}
```